# How can I mine dogecoins on debian?

Tags: linux, dogecoin

How can I mine dogecoins on debian? I have tried to compile cudaminer but I can't find out how to install nvcc.

Answer (score 1):

Definetly! Dogecoin uses the Scrypt algorithm so that means any Litecoin tutorial can be used as a drop-in replacement tutorial. Just be sure to use the proper pool address and port.

A google search brings me this nice looking guide:

[Debian 6.0.7 - GPU Miner install guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/132505278/Debian-GPU-Litecoin-cgminer-install-guide)